# Need an algorithm for this problem

Tags: algorithm

There are two integer sequences A[] and B[] of length N,both unsorted.

Requirement: through the swapping of elements between A[] and B[]( can randomly exchange, not with same index), make the difference between {the sum of all elements in A[]} and {the sum of all elements in B[]} to be minimum.

PS: actually,it is an interview question I encountered.

Many thanks

Comment: Does the swap have to take place at the same index of each sequence?

Comment: You're really going to need to add more detail to this if you want any serious answers.

Comment: we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Please provide your thoughts on the solution at this point. The community wants to work _with_ you, not _for_ you.

Comment: @fbrereto: someone told me this problem is NP-Complete related,i'm confused about it

Comment: Retagged homework as interview-questions. @Heisenburgor. 'Someone' is right. It is NP-Complete, see my answer.

Comment: @Moron: Yes,he told me the same thing,i think i gotta learn that stuff first,thanks

Comment: As with *nearly* all interview questions, the answer itself is unimportant.  The important part is how you go about doing it.  What did you try?

Comment: @Chris Lively: i tried to merge them together then sort with ascending order, then split it into two sequences again with odd/even indexes,then swap two elements with same index one by one,and compute and result one by one.
it's actually stupid, i have to learn these stuffs first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is going to be NP-hard! I believe you can do a reduction from [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) to this.

<strike>As per BlueRaja/polygene's comments, I will try to provide a full reduction from Subset Sum.</strike>

Here is a reduction:

Subset Sum problem: Given integers x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, is there some non-empty subset which sums to zero?

Our problem: Given two integer arrays of size k, find the minimum possible difference of the sum of the two arrays, assuming we can shuffle around the integers in the arrays, treating both arrays as one array.

Say we had a polynomial time algo for our problem.

Say now you are given integers  T = {x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>, ...,x<sub>n</sub>} (multiset)

Let S<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + ...+ x<sub>n</sub> + x<sub>i</sub>.

Let T<sub>i</sub> = {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>i-1</sub>, x<sub>i+1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub> }  ( = T - x<sub>i</sub>)

Define

A<sub>i</sub> = Array formed using T<sub>i</sub>

B<sub>i</sub> = [S<sub>i</sub>, 0, ..., 0] (i.e one element is S<sub>i</sub> and rest are zeroes).

Let m<sub>i</sub> = the min difference found by our problem for arrays A<sub>i</sub> and B<sub>i</sub>

(we run our problem n times).

Claim: Some non-empty subset of T sums to zero if and only if, there is some i, for which m<sub>i</sub> = 0.

Proof: (wlog) say x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + .. + x<sub>k</sub> = 0

Then

A = [x<sub>k+1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, 0, ...0]

B = [x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ..., x<sub>k</sub>, S<sub>1</sub>, 0, ..0]

gives the minimum difference m<sub>1</sub> to be |x<sub>2</sub> + .. + x<sub>k</sub> + (x<sub>1</sub> + ... + x<sub>n</sub>) + x<sub>1</sub> - (x<sub>k+1</sub> + .. + x<sub>n</sub>)| = |2(x<sub>1</sub>+ x<sub>2</sub> + .. x<sub>k</sub>)| = 0.

Similarly the if part can be proved.

In fact, this actually also follows (more easily) from Partition too: just create new array with all zeroes.

Hoepfully I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: This is equivent to having the contents of A and B in a single collection, then performing bin packing, which is np-hard.

Comment: @fatcat1111: You need to go the other way for proving NP-Hardness. Take a hard problem and reduce that to the current problem. In this case, Subset sum is easily reduced to this problem.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: I have edited the answer to point to wiki page which has this.

Comment: This is not the partition problem - the sizes of the "halves" are fixed in this case.

Comment: @BlueRaja, @polygenelubricants: I have edited the post to show the reduction.

Answer (score 3):

Take any instance of the NP-complete [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem):

> Partition a multiset A of positive integers into two multisets B and C with the same sum

like {a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>}. Add n zeroes {0,0,0...,0,a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>} and ask if the set can be partitioned into two multisets A and B with the same sum and same number of elements. I claim these two conditions are equivalent:

- If A and B are a solution to the problem, then you can strike out the zeroes and get a solution of partiton problem.
- If there is a solution to the partition problem, for example a<sub>i1</sub> + a<sub>i2</sub> + ... a<sub>ik</sub> = a<sub>j1</sub> + ... +a<sub>jl</sub> where {a<sub>i1</sub>, a<sub>i2</sub>, a<sub>ik</sub>, a<sub>j1</sub>, ..., a<sub>jl</sub>} = {a<sub>1</sub>, ... , a<sub>n</sub>} then obviously k+l = n. Add l zeroes to the left side and k zeroes to the right side and you'll get 0  + ... + 0 + a<sub>i1</sub> + a<sub>i2</sub> + ... a<sub>ik</sub> = 0 + ... + 0 + a<sub>j1</sub> + ... +a<sub>jl</sub>, whichi is a solution of your problem.

So, this is a reduction (so the problem is NP-hard) and the problem is NP, so it is NP-complete.

Comment: Yes, it is the partition problem with 2 partitions that must have the same number of elements in each partition. Thus, it is NP-Complete.

Comment: @Justin: This is not the partition problem, for the reasons you just mentioned.  @sdcvvc: You gave a reduction from this to partition problem (which proves nothing), not the other way around. For instance, say we have `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15}`.  A solution to this problem will give us `{1, 2, 15}, {3, 4, 5}`.  Is there any way to use that information to determine if there are two subsets with the same sum?

Comment: @BlueRaja, ok, I think I must be misunderstanding what the problem being asked is then. I'll look over it again.

Comment: +1 you convinced me that this is NP-complete.  This answer deserves a ✔.

Answer (score 2):

"sequences A[] and B[] of length N" -> does this mean both A and B are *each* of length N?

(For the purpose of clarity I am using 1-based arrays below).

If so, how about this:

1. Assume A[1..N] and B[1..N]
2. Concatenate A and B into a new array C of length 2N: C[1..N] <- A[1..N]; C[N+1 .. 2N] <- B[1..N]
3. Sort C in ascending order.
4. Take the first *pair* of numbers from C; send the first element (C[1]) to A[1] and second element (C[2]) to B[1]
5. Take the second pair of numbers from C; this time send the *second* element (C[4]) to A[2] and the *first* element (C[3]) to B[2] (the order of elements in the pair sent to A and B is the opposite of 3)
6. ... repeat 3 and 4 until C is exhausted

The observation here is that, in a sorted array, an adjacent pair of numbers will have the smallest difference (compared to a pair of numbers from non-adjacent positions). Step 3 ensures that A[1] and B[1] consists of a pair of numbers with the least possible difference. Step 4 ensures that (a) A[2] and B[2] consist of a pair of numbers with the least possible difference (from the available numbers) and also (b) that the difference is opposite in sign from step 3. By continuing like this, we are ensuring that A[i] and B[i] contain numbers with the least possible difference. Also, by flipping the order in which we send elements to A and B, we are ensuring that the difference changes sign for each successive i.

Answer (score 1):

Try being greedy about it.  Given such limited information, I'm not sure what else one could put out there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will ensure the minimum possible distance, but the first thing that comes to mi mind is something like this:

```
int diff=0;
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        int x = a[i] - b[i];
        if (abs(diff - x) > abs(diff + x)){
             swap(a,b,i);
             diff-=x;
        }else{
             diff+=x;
        }

    }
```

assuming that you have a swap function which takes the two arrays and exchanges the items at position i :)

computing and adding the difference between the two values at position i you get the incremental difference between the sums of the elements of the two arrays.
at each step you check if it's better to add (a[i]-b[i]) or (b[i]-a[i]). if the b[i]-a[i] it's the case, you swap the elements at position i in the arrays.

Maybe this will not be the best way, but it should be a start :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NP-Complete.

We can reduce the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) to the **decision version** of this problem, i.e. given two arrays of ints of the same size, determine whether items can be swapped so that the sums are equal.

The input to the partition problem: a set S of integers, of size N

In order to transform this input into an input to our problem, we define A to be an array of all items in S, and B an array of the same size, with B[i]=0 for all i. This transformation is linear in the input size.

It is clear that our algorithm applied on A and B returns true if and only if there is a partition of S into 2 subsets such that the sums are equal.